# Cannot install Search API pages module, due to database errors?

Tags: installation, search

Trying to install search_api_page created repeated database errors about the search_api_page table not being available.

Is it a known problem known to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue.  I resolved it by installing search api on a fresh drupal install and exporting the databases then importing to the original database.  I would **not** recommend doing this first however.

First you should uncheck search api module in your modules list, then click the uninstall tab and uninstall it.  Grab a new copy of the search api module to make sure you didn't have corrupt files and install it again.  If this doesn't work, then you may want to try what I had to do.